# Cannot use -fsanitize=address in g++-11

Tags: c++, standards-compliance

I tryed to use `-fsanitize=address` option in g++-11. However, ld showed an error message when I executed command.

Environment:

- OS: macOS Monterery Version 12.1 Beta (21C5021h)
- Arch: arm64
- g++-11:

```
❯ g++-11 --version
g++-11 (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_1) 11.1.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Source code:

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5 };
    std::cout << v.at(5) << std::endl;
}
```

Command and Error message:

```
❯ g++-11 -fsanitize=address main.cpp
ld: library not found for -lasan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: maybe you should install `libasan5`